# Multidimensional PHP array stays empty

Tags: php, mysql, multidimensional-array, while-loop

I'm trying to create a multidimensional array within a PHP function. But it doesn't seem to work. The function I wrote:

```
//Get newsitems
function getNews() {
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM news WHERE archived='0' ORDER BY `id` DESC")
    or die(mysql_error());

    $array = array();

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

        $array[] =  array ( 'title' => $row['title'], 
                            'content' => $row['content'], 
                            'date' => $row['pagid'], 
                            'image' => $row['image'], 
                            'youtube' => $row['youtube']

    }

    return $array;
}
```

Then I'm trying to get an array by doing this:

```
$aNews = getNews();
```

When I print this array nothing is showed. What am I doing wrong? The database query doesn't return any errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a syntax error, you didn't close the parenthesis and terminate the line around the array.

Change to:

```
    $array[] =  array ( 'title' => $row['title'], 
                        'content' => $row['content'], 
                        'date' => $row['pagid'], 
                        'image' => $row['image'], 
                        'youtube' => $row['youtube'] ); // <-- this
```

You should be getting a fatal error because of this, a white screen usually indicates a fatal error but with error reporting/display turned off. For future debugging you can view your error log or turn errors on:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
```

Side notes:

- The `mysql_*` library is deprecated, consider upgrading to a modern API such as MySQLi or PDO.
- If you must use this library, at least change to `mysql_fetch_assoc()` because you're only interested in the associative array.

Comment: Thanks. I had a syntax error indeed. But the problem I had regarding getting nothing back from the function still exists..

Comment: Then it looks like no rows were returned from the query. See what this outputs after the query: `var_dump(mysql_num_rows($result));`

Comment: var_dump returns nothing. That's weird because this query should return something..

Comment: What do you mean nothing? it should either output a number (could be 0) or `false` on failure.

Comment: I have added the var_dump in my function in $error and then return $error; Then when I echo getNews(); I get nothing. I hope I am explaining this clearly.

Comment: I would add the var_dump right after the query and before the while loop. So for example: `echo 'Total rows: '; var_dump(mysql_num_rows($result));`

Comment: function getNews() {
 $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM news WHERE archived='0' ORDER BY `id` DESC")
 or die(mysql_error());
 
 $dump = var_dump(mysql_num_rows($result));
 
 $array = array();
 
 while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  
  $array[] =  array ( 'title' => $row['title'], 
       'content' => $row['content'], 
       'date' => $row['pagid'], 
       'image' => $row['image'], 
       'youtube' => $row['youtube'] );
  
 }
 
 return $dump;
}

Comment: var_dump doesn't return anything, so you can't return it from the function. It just outputs the variable there on the spot. Try adding `die('stopped');` after the var_dump to stop any further execution.

Comment: Finally I got things working. Thanks for taking your time to help me out. I will accept this answer (Y).